# Office JS API sends back garbage content for mail body(when body contains accented characters)

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have noticed that the Office JS API has recently started sending back  random text when a  mail body contains accented characters. This seems to only happen when the coercion type is "html" as shown below:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", function(x) { console.log(x.value)});
```

Is this a bug?

Reference

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-1.5#getasync-coerciontype--options--callback-

Comment: Does it happen in browser, windows outlook desktop or mac outlook desktop?

Comment: Windows 10 - Outlook 2016

Comment: Could you share your outlook build number. It would also be helpful if you shared the body of the message on which this issue reproduces so we can try on our end.

Comment: I'll reach out and get the build number. However, I don't think we can get the mail body

Comment: We weren't able to reproduce this issue on the recent builds of Outlook Desktop. Here's the string we used to test it "a b c o u z ä ö ü". Could you try testing it with this? Also, sharing a sample line from the body (instead of the whole body) that you believe is causing the issue is going to be helpful for us to see what exactly is going on by testing that line on the same build number you mention you see the issue on.